# Configure real domain to suddomain (wildcard subdomain)?

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, wildcard

We are providing blog platform and we separate each user with wildcard subdomain (aaa.testweb.com).  We would like our user to be able to switch to his domain (www.aaa.com) if he wants to.  How to configure the Apache server to support following scenarios?

Please advise if there are more to configure besides the httpd.conf.

EX:
1. Go to **www.aaa.com** and show content of **aaa.testweb.com**
(URL in address bar is **www.aaa.com**)
2. Go to **www.aaa.com/content** and show content of **aaa.testweb.com/content**
(URL in address bar is **www.aaa.com/content**)

Comment: For every user, aaa, bbb, ccc, etc, you're gong to register a domain for them?

Answer (score 0):

There are already lots of questions on StackOverflow that cover this topic, but I'll chime in and add my two cents' worth anyway. :) Going by my experience, this should do the trick...

Before I cover details: In a nutshell, what you'll need to do is set what information Apache serves when it receives a request. I'm assuming here that whether your customers use one of your subdomains or their own domain, your server will still be hosting the blog? In which case the important part is the ServerName in your customer's VirtualHost directive.

Below are examples of these two scenarios using your example URI, first using a subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aaa.testweb.com
DocumentRoot /public_html/customers/aaa_html
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

And second using a dedicated domain name:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.aaa.com
DocumentRoot /public_html/customers/aaa_html
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

From the DNS side, there should be an A record for each relevant subdomain pointing to your web host in order for a request of "aaa.testweb.com" to hit your server. You could do this rather easily with pointing *.testweb.com to your server, however this would route all subdomain requests on that domain to your server; if the requested subdomain doesn't exist, the default domain site will be served instead.

I may be mistaken here, but I think setting custom A records for each new subdomain as needed would help to keep better control of the situation in the long run.

If a customer then wants to switch from one option to the other, the only update that's required on your Apache server is the ServerName rule for their VirtualHost. DNS records would be configured through the relevant domain registrar.